# Path to the sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to connect to connect to a sample database "chinook", from a java class, chrisDB.java which is part of a web project. 
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:chinook.db";
The path above gives me an error. My folder structure is this:

[image: FOLDER STRUCTURE]

I just can't figure out where to copy chinook or how to find the relative path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved using a servlet and get the path with getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
This is just a workaround though, I hoped I could find a way using a method from the class.